# Location for user_parameter_sanitizer.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Recommendation from [GitHub devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

> If you have multiple Devise models, you may want to set up a
>   different parameter sanitizer per model. In this case, we recommend
>   inheriting from `Devise::ParameterSanitizer` and adding your own
>   logic:
>
> ```
> class User::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
>   def initialize(*)
>     super
>     permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :email])
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> And then configure your controllers to use it:
>
> ```
> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>   protected
>
>   def devise_parameter_sanitizer
>     if resource_class == User
>       User::ParameterSanitizer.new(User, :user, params)
>     else
>       super # Use the default one
>     end
>   end
> end"
> ```

Where should I create the file `user_parameter_sanitizer.rb` to host the code?
The info given by the devise GitHub page is excellent, but I am new to Rails and coding in general.